# Solving for the value of $t$ in $4t^3-t-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Solve for $t$:
>   $$4t^3-t-1=0$$

I couldn't use polynomial. I tried this:

$t(4t^2-1)-1=0$ but then again it doesn't make sense to solve $t$ from that

Comment: If you are asked to *solve for the roots* of $4t^3-t-1$, i.e. find which values of $t$ satisfy $4t^3-t-1=0$, then you can use [cardano's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients) but noone memorizes it.  Otherwise, it will be very difficult to do by hand.

Comment: @projectilemotion's point with his comments is that "$4t^3-t-1$" is not an equation as it has no equals sign, it is an *expression*.  This is just how "$5$" is not an equation.  This has no truth value associated to it.  Equations are true or false.  Expressions don't have any intrinsic truth value.  On the other hand "$4t^3-t-1=0$" is a perfectly valid equation and there will be certain values of $t$ which make it true and other values of $t$ which make it false.  Solving an equation is generally finding which values of the variables present will make the equation true.

Answer (score 0):

A [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_solution_to_the_cubic_equation_with_real_coefficients).
This one has one real root:
$$ \frac16\,\sqrt [3]{27+3\,\sqrt {78}}+{\frac {1}{2 \sqrt [3]{27+3\,
\sqrt {78}}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have a depressed cubic equation $t^3+pt+q=0$, a good idea is to use [Vieta's substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Vieta.27s_substitution) $t=w-\frac p {3w}$

$$t^3+pt+q=0\implies w^3+q-\frac{p^3}{27w^3}=0\implies w^6+qw^3-\frac{p^3}{27}=0$$ which is a quadratic equation in $w^3$.

In your case $p=q=-\frac 14$ which gives $$w^3=\frac{9+\sqrt{78}}{72}\implies t=\frac{\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{78}}}{2\ 3^{2/3}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt[3]{3
   \left(9+\sqrt{78}\right)}}$$

If you want to look fancy, you also could use the [hyperbolic solution for one real root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root) and get $$t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(3 \sqrt{3}\right)\right)$$